# Parsing name/value pairs containing spaces delimited by spaces

Tags: string, vb.net, parsing, split

I'm trying to parse a file in vb.net. This file is the output of a CLI command on Mikrotik RouterOS.
The file looks like this, where the \ and the end of the line means the line continues below

```
# jan/03/2017 12:46:35 by RouterOS 6.38
# software id = 3BQ2-2I1I
#
/queue simple
add dst=WAN max-limit=5M/20M name=Compartido01 priority=1/1 queue=\
    wireless-default/wireless-default target="" total-priority=1
add max-limit=512k/2M name="6206101450 - Simone Walter (2M) (P13)" parent=\
    Compartido01 target=190.211.88.1/32
add max-limit=350k/1M name=\
    "6206130537 - Figueroa Viviana del Carmen (1M) (P14)" parent=Compartido01 \
    target=190.211.88.24/32
```

I managed to skip the 4 first lines and collapse them so they look like this

```
"add dst=WAN max-limit=5M/20M name=Compartido01 priority=1/1 queue=wireless-default/wireless-default target="" total-priority=1"
"add max-limit=512k/2M name="6206101450 - Simone Walter (2M) (P13)" parent=Compartido01 target=190.211.88.1/32"
"add max-limit=350k/1M name="6206130537 - Figueroa Viviana del Carmen (1M) (P14)" parent=Compartido01 target=190.211.88.24/32"
```

What I need to do is to extract the information on those strings, something like "name=XXXXXX" and "target=XXXXX"
I could split using space as delimiter but the "name" field can have spaces inside it
Anyone can give me a hint ?

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a RegEx match parser...Found one [here](http://www.darinhiggins.com/parsing-key-value-pairs-via-regular-expressions/). See if you can make what you need from this.

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Module Parser

    Public Function ParseKeyValuePairs(ByVal Buffer As String) As Dictionary(Of String, String)
        Dim Result = New Dictionary(Of String, String)

        '---- There are 3 sub patterns contained here, seperated at the | characters
        '     The first retrieves name="value", honoring doubled inner quotes
        '     The second retrieves name=value where value can't contain spaces
        '     The third retrieves name alone, where there is no "=value" part (ie a "flag" key
        '        where simply its existance has meaning
        Dim Pattern = "(?:(?<key>[\w-]+)\s*\=\s*""(?<value>[^""]*(?:""""[^""]*)*)"") | " & _
                      "(?:(?<key>[\w-]+)\s*\=\s*(?<value>[^""\s]*)) | " & _
                      "(?:(?<key>[\w-]+)\s*)"
        Dim r = New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(Pattern, RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace)

        '---- parse the matches
        Dim m As System.Text.RegularExpressions.MatchCollection = r.Matches(Buffer)

        '---- break the matches up into Key value pairs in the return dictionary
        For Each Match As System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match In m
            Result.Add(Match.Groups("key").Value, Match.Groups("value").Value)
        Next
        Return Result
    End Function

    Public Sub Main()
        Dim s = "Key1=Value Key2=""My Value here"" Key3=Test Key4 Key5"
        Dim r = ParseKeyValuePairs(s)
        For Each i In r
            Debug.Print(i.Key & "=" & i.Value)
        Next
    End Sub
End Module
```